# Is the Akka Actors library installed with the Scala IDE for Scala 2.10?

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, akka, actor

I have recently begun exploring Scala, and have started by installing the Scala IDE in my copy of Eclipse (Indigo). I initially installed the Scala IDE for Scala 2.9, but then noticed that there was a newer release available for Scala 2.10. Installing the newer plug-in over the older one seems to have worked, but...

Scala 2.10 has deprecated the older Scala Actors in favor of Akka Actors. Thus I'm trying to add an import to my toy Scala project:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
```

This is flagged in the IDE with the error

```
not found: object akka
```

When I look at my Scala project's properties, I indeed do not see any of the akka-* jar files that are mentioned in the Akka documentation.

Do they need to be downloaded and installed separately, even though the Scala IDE plug-in installed the rest of Scala 2.10? Or have package names changed as part of integrating Akka actors in place of the older Scala Actors? (The documentation doesn't say so, but the Scala 2.10 release is fairly recent...)

Comment: Did you add the akka libs to your build.sbt (whatever that is in scala IDE)?

Comment: I do not see any akka-* jar files to add to the project's class path... But admittedly they may be buried somewhere in the confusing folder hierarchy Eclipse uses to isolate plug-ins. I'm trying to determine if I should download the Akka jars independently or if they are supposed to be bundled in the Scala 2.10 release somewhere...

Comment: Nope, you need to add akka to sbt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Akka artifacts are not bundled with the Scala IDE (yet), you will have to add “akka-actor_2.10” and friends to your project’s dependencies.

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming my suspicion... I've resolved this by grabbing the separate Scala 2.10 distribution and then adding the relevant tar files from its `lib` folder to my Scala project's class path.

Comment: How do I `add “akka-actor_2.10”`, where?

Comment: It is simplest to get started with Activator, which will create Eclipse projects for you: http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted

Answer (score 5):

No, they aren't packaged together.

The easiest way to make sure the Eclipse IDE can see your dependencies (Akka, and anything else referenced in your build.sbt file) is to let `sbt` do it using the `sbteclipse` plugin.  Here's the instructions I wrote up for co-workers:

---

**Install the "sbteclipse" plugin**

This plugin will allow sbt to add the files/references that Eclipse needs to find all the dependencies that you specify in your build.sbt.  Otherwise, you will be able to use the IDE, but you will seek all kinds of "object not found" errors.

Just make sure the plugin is being added in your global *plugins.sbt* file.  This file (and it's path) may not exist so you may need to create it at the following location:

```
~/.sbt $ cd ~/.sbt/0.13/
~/.sbt/0.13 $ mkdir plugins
```

Edit/create the *plugins.sbt* file:

```
~/.sbt/0.13 $ vi plugins/plugins.sbt
```

then add this line (it may be the only line in the file):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")
```

**Running sbteclipse**

To use this, you just navigate to a scala project on the commandline and run the following.  If you already had Eclipse open, go ahead and restart it.

```
/sites/ewuser (master)$ sbt eclipse
```

References:

- [How to initialize a new Scala project in sbt, Eclipse and github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381294/how-to-initialize-a-new-scala-project-in-sbt-eclipse-and-github)
- [Official sbteclipse plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse)

Comment: You can find out latest version of sbteclipse plugin on the official repo: https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse

Answer (score 0):

Download the akka for eclipse from below location

http://downloads.typesafe.com/akka/akka_2.11-2.4.1.zip?_ga=1.167921254.618585520.1450199987

extract the zip

add dependencies from the lib folder into project