# How to initialize a new Scala project in sbt, Eclipse and github

Tags: eclipse, git, scala, sbt

How to initialize a new Scala project in sbt, Eclipse and github, so that it all plays together...

Answer (score 30):

A new Scala project typically requires being set up for sbt, eclipse (if you so choose) and github such that it all works together. After investing some time on this setup, it may help to have this list for aligning these 3 tools/services, for as long as simpler ways are not available. The series of steps that works for me follows. It assumes you have the Scala IDE plugin installed in eclipse.

1. Create a new repo [in Github](https://github.com/new).
2. Decide a directory location for the new project
3. In eclipse, use the Git Repositories View to import the Github repo into that location. Alternatively you can use command line git for that.
4. Locate to that same location you've chosen for the project and run `sbt eclipse`. This makes sure eclipse will be able to handle the sbt project structure, so that your project can be built by sbt while also being intelligible for eclipse. If `sbt eclipse` doesn't work, the sbt eclipse plugin is probably not installed in sbt - [install it](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse).
5. In eclipse, use `File --> Import --> General --> Existing Projects into Workspace`, selecting that same location, so that eclipse builds its project structure for the file structure having just been prepared by sbt.
6. Make git ignore all but the core of your new project by updating the .gitignore file to ignore eclipse and sbt files. The following seems to be currently fine.

   ```
   *.class
   *.log

   # sbt specific
   dist/*
   target/
   lib_managed/
   src_managed/
   project/boot/
   project/plugins/project/

   # Scala-IDE specific
   .scala_dependencies

   # Eclipse specific
   .project
   .classpath
   .cache
   ```

You should now be able to run the project in eclipse, and in sbt, and commit and push code changes through git. To see the empty project run, which may very well make sense at this stage, you can add a scala class in eclipse to it, containing merely the following code. Note that scala sources should typically sit under src/main/scala. If this path doesn't exist yet, create it through e.g. `mkdir -p src/main/scala` on Unix.

```
object hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Main starting")  
  }
}
```

Or alternatively only this code:

```
object app extends App {
  println("Application starting")  
}
```

It should work now.
Need to disclaim that future versions of eclipse, sbt, etc may render this outdated.
If this is dead wrong in your environment, you can add a better answer.

Comment: This is very valuable. Would you like to turn this into a Tutorial on the [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/documentation.html) docs page?

Comment: Sure. Maybe just a link to here though?

Comment: Here's how to install the sbt eclipse plugin in sbt (step 2):  `mkdir -p ~/.sbt/plugins && echo 'addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.2")' >> ~/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt && sbt`

Comment: When I ignore .project and .classpath, my project does not seem to port properly. Any thoughts on what it is for? Do you setup new .project and .classpath files for each environment?

Comment: Port? other people may not use eclipse, and some deployment environments, e.g. Heroku, do not need a .classpath file. That had been the rational for excluding them from git. You are correct that you cannot pull the same github repo into a new machine and reuse it in eclipse without adding those files. I'd just typically leave it to the crowd to pick their own IDE rather than include those files in a repo, but it's your choice. Hope this helps, if not, maybe read a little about how to create a new eclipse project?

Comment: You may currently alternatively try this getting started application from typesafe, called [the Activator](https://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted). Not sure it's much easier though.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer/s is/are of high importance as well as the question since these tools are not self explanatory. Based on personal experience with this challenge which seemed impossible but when one acknowledges few key insurance policy  reference points things will become reality:

1. Implementation of development environment may require radical
   re-installation as new tool is adopted (if you adopt GIT after you
   already had SBT in place you may need to empty SBT's working
   directory as GIT require the cloning process to have empty house on
   local working directory)
2. Keep really well updated backups especially when considering
   re-setting any of this "domino" environment layers as some of the GUI
   or command initiated cleansing operations truly take care of that
   sometimes with surprising effectiveness and without any regard to
   other tools / layers requirements
3. Keep really good documentation (including previous pragmatic answer) on key stages to
   make things a reality (again)